# WebService calling other WebService - weird behavior

Tags: vb.net, web-services, logging, soap

I have a weird issue with my WebServices logging.

We provide a back-end service to a company. They host the front end and use our WS to pull client data. When they call our WS, we call their WS to validate the user and proceed if everything is fine or return error code for any other reason (exceptions, timeouts, etc).

They have been having issues with our WebServices (timeouts, low performance) so we introduced logging into the WS to try and track the Request/Response timings. The WS logging consists of 2 records - Request and Response.

The request record is created as soon as the WS is called and includes all relevant information client provided (account number, phone, etc). It also generates and logs with request a unique HashId, which is the link between request and response. Without HashId it would be difficult to link request/response, because response may come 10 seconds later and the log would have thousands of records in between.

The response is created at the end of the WS and it logs response and HashID created earlier.

Every WS has error trapping, if an exception happens, an error log will be written with the HashID created at the start of the WS call.

Here is the question:
about 90-95% of requests have corresponding responses. However, there are records where there is a request, but no response with corresponding HashID and no exception. Whats even more weird is, we have a response with no corresponding request log! How can that be if the very first step is to log request and HashId is assigned only once? One thing to note - traffic is heavy, 10 to 20 unique calls per second.

Here is a very simple WS we have (I cut some lines, but the principle remains the same - log request, initialize WS object and response object, call the other WS, log response if no exception or log error if exception):

```
Public Function getAccountBills(ByVal AccountID As String, Optional ByVal PinCode As String = "") As Boolean
    Dim request As New Bills.getAccountBills
    Dim response1 As Bills.getAccountBillsResponse
    Dim client As New Bills.AccountBillsRetrieveClient
    Dim hashID As String = ""
    Try
        ' generate unique HashID using supplied parameters, date and a random string
        hashID = GetLogHash(AccountID & PinCode & Now.ToString & GetRandomString)
        'log request with HashID and client supplied parameters
        Log(String.Format("REQUEST ({3}): HashID=[{0}], AccountID=[{1}], PinCode=[{2}]", hashID, AccountID, PinCode))

        ' set up WS object
        SetupWebService(client, "AccountBillSummaryRetrieve")

        ' setup a response object 
        request.AccountBillsRetrieveV1Request = New Bills.AccountBillsRetrieveV1Request

        ' call client WS with paramaters and get a response
        response1 = client.retrieveAccountBills("ABCD", "1234", request)

        ' log response with HashID
        Log(String.Format("RESPONSE ({1}) OK: HashID=[{0}]", hashID))
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log
        Log(String.Format("RESPONSE ({1}) ERROR: HashID=[{0}] Error=[{1}]", hashID, ex.ToString))
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: 'When they call our WS, we call their WS to validate the user and proceed' Why dont you use a Token or Security Certificate. Making a call back to thier service with every call to your service has got to be killing you!

Comment: It's the way the system was designed, there are actually 3 independent systems - 1 on our side and 2 on theirs. Funny part is, the 2 systems on their end do not talk to each other.

Comment: If your running into slowness and have 10-20 calls per second, you should think about a redesign. This will always be your bottleneck! Sorry I'm not helping your actual issue.

Comment: We do not see slowness on our side (logs prove it). We suspect the slowness is due to delay when calling external WS. The log before calling external WS and right after it seem to prove they are the bottleneck, however, sometimes I see the log that is after the call to WS, but not the one before and was wondering how that is possible

Comment: Do you have some type of error handling that will jump out of writing the log if there is an error? With 10-20 per second, you could be running into contention issues with the IO when writing to the log. What I have done with my logging to prevent the IO from slowing my web service down is I put the entry into a collection and then have another thread (idle) take the info from the collection and write it to the HD. This prevents the log from slowing things down. Then, in your thread that writes the log, only remove it from the collection if it was save to file successfully. ...

Comment: If there is an error, perform cleanup, wait 1 second, then try again.

Comment: Yes, I have error handling, at which point I write a log with the HashId generated as soon as you enter the function - so each unique call to our WS should produce 2 lines of logs. First line is Request log and 2nd line is either response log or error log. The logging doesn't seem to slow down the system much. Most of our WS do not call their WS and we do not have any complaints there.